# Debugging ASP.NET Core applications running in IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, asp.net-core

Is there any way to debug an ASP.NET Core web application while running under IIS?

I'm running under IIS because I need it to be available over SSL on port 443.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

1. Publish web application with Debug configuration
2. Set up web site on IIS as described [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html)
3. Open web site in browser to have dotnet process started
4. In Visual Studio open Debug -> Attach to Process or press Ctrl+Alt+P
5. Make sure in "Attach to" line you have "Automatic" or "Managed (v4.6, v4.5, v4.0)". If not, press select and choose "Automatically determine the type of code to debug"
6. Check "Show processes from all users"
7. **Select `dotnet.exe` and press Attach**

Note: If you see several dnx.exe processes, choose the one with IIS user in column username. By default it is "IIS APPPOOL{your app pool name}"

P.S. If you see dotnet process with empty username, run Visual studio as Administrator

### UPDATE

With ASP.Net Core 1.0.0 you must attach to "{youprojectnamet.exe}". E.g. if you project has name "Web", you must attach to "Web.exe"
Also you can find name of the executive in the following section of web.config

```
<system.webServer>
   <aspNetCore processPath=".\Web.exe" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This works but I note that you can't step into the dotnet core framework code or even see the real names of things in the callstack for the frameworks. If anybody finds some way to do that please update this answer.

Comment: Any luck with this? I can't to get it to work? I published debug, and tried to attach in so many ways. It just won't hit my breakpoint.

Comment: How do you publish an application with debug configuration?

Comment: Right click on the project, choose Publish, on settings tab choose Configuration that starts with word Debug

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding attaching to the projectname.exe.  It's just habit attaching to IISExpress.exe.

Comment: I tried with w3wp.exe numerous times, all i needed was step 7. Thank you!

Comment: There is two dotnet.exe process but I only run one site which one should I choose to debug?

Comment: doublnt, The second one is probably running on IIS express. You can close IIS Express (it's in taskbar) or just select dotnet.exe that runs from IIS user. On Windows 10 by default it's "IIS APPPOOL\Unmanaged".

Comment: I want to point out one thing. You'll not see dotnet.exe until you'll browse your site at least one time from the browser that is hosted on IIS.

Comment: That's covered by step 3 - Open your site in browser

Comment: Aha! Good reminder to use `dotnet.exe`. There was me connecting to `w3wp.exe`. No wonder it didn't work. Old habits die hard!

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1273958/Debugging-ASP-NET-Core-applications-within-IIS

Answer (score 10):

### Scenario : Debugging ASP.NET Core Web Application running on IIS Local.

**Prerequisite**: Add "Development time IIS support" to your existing Visual Studio installation. Follow the next link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/07/13/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/

---

**1. In Visual Studio 2017 create "ASP.NET Core Web Application" with name "MvcMovie".**

1.1. Open "MvcMovie" project **Properties**.

1.1.2. Go to "**Debug**" tab and set(if not):

1.1.2.1. "Profile:" "MvcMovie".

1.1.2.2. "Launch:" "IIS"

1.1.2.3. (checked)"Launch browser:" "https://localhost"

1.1.2.4. "Environment variables:" | Name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
                                     | Value: "Development" |

1.1.2.5. "Web Server Settings"

1.1.2.5.1. "App URL:" "https://localhost"

1.1.2.5.2. (checked)"Enable Anonymous Authentication"

### [image]

---

**2. In "IIS Local" manager "Add Website" with name "AspNetCoreMvcMovie".**

2.1. Set "Physical path" with the project(NOT the solution) folder(in our case "D:\ASP-NET-Core\ASP-NET-Core-Projects\MvcMovie\MvcMovie").

2.2. Binding "Type" : "https".

2.3. "SSL certificate" : "IIS Express Development Certificate".

2.4. Click "OK".

2.5. Into "Application Pools" find by name "AspNetCoreMvcMovie" pool.

2.5.1. Into "Edit Application Pool" set ".NET CLR version" to "No Managed Code".

2.5.2. Click "OK".

[image]

---

**3. Set VS 2017 elevated permissions.**

3.1. If we have massage like that: "Microsoft Visual Studio": "This task requires the application to have elevated permissions", follow troubleshooting "(Method 2) Troubleshoot Compatibility" in next link:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/46441.visual-studio-2017-this-task-requires-the-application-to-have-elevated-permissions.aspx

3.2 After accomplishment of this method(Method 2), VS-2017 will start.

3.3. Run(in "Debug" mode) "MvcMovie" application with IIS-profile(which is set to run on IIS Local... !!! NOT the IIS Express !!!). In our case profile is set with name of the current application("MvcMovie") in "Step 1.".

3.4. Wait application to run in browser.

3.5. Close application(close web-browser).

3.6. Go to compatibility-troubleshooting-window and click "Next".

3.6.1. Then click on "-> Yes, save these settings for this program".

3.6.2. After "Resolving issues" finishes "Saving settings", we have to view window "Troubleshooting has completed". In the window "Troubleshooting has completed", have to view : "Issues found" -> "Incompatible Program" -> "Fixed". Then click on "-> Close the troubleshooter".

**4. From VS-2017, Run(in "Debug" mode) again "MvcMovie" application with IIS-profile(in our case with name "MvcMovie").**

[image]

---

Comment: Very useful answer. For VS2019 / ASP.NET Core 5 solution, I also had to install [Development time IIS support for ASP.NET Core Applications](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/) which seems to have dealt with automatically creating the IIS Web application and its application pool.

Comment: For VS2022, follow the link provided above (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/) and following the section for editing the launchSettings.json worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

The benefit is you can actually use the website outside using an actual hostname. Imagine having an android app trying to connect to localhost to debug an asp.net core web api service. a pain to setup unless you can actually use an actual physical ip address and connect to something running on iis. Just like BEFORE. Everything can be done but it doesn't mean if it's new it's automatically more practical. And not having the old debug iis option is a step backwards in terms of productivity.

Comment: My use case was I was writing an Alexa service which communicates to my box via https on 443.

Comment: I mean, useful discussion, but can you say how this answers the OP's question?

Answer (score 6):

Is this really necessary? ASP.NET Core applications run as an external process to IIS (using dotnet.exe) so there's really nothing gained by debugging through IIS. The backend application gets requests over plain HTTP.

For more info how the actual IIS hosting works with ASP.NET Core you might want to check out this blog post:
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS

Visual Studio currently doesn't support debugging under full IIS and from what I've heard this is not something that is planned either. Microsoft does support running with IIS Express and you can set up a certificate for IIS Express.

In the ASP.NET Core project, in the Debug Project options there's an *Enable SSL* option that you can enable. IIS Express will create a local certificate and let you debug your application using SSL.

The benefit with this approach is that it just works by pressing F5 - no manual attachment required.

[image]

Comment: It enables "save/reload" scenarios for views without compiling, doesn't it?

Comment: Visual Studio does and always has supported debugging under full IIS.

Comment: What if i need to debug requests from other machines/devices? Does IIS Express handle remote connections?

Comment: Bonner - but not ASP.NET Core debugging. Not like outlined by Vitaly using explicit process attachment to Kestrel. 
Lserson - IIS Express can be used for remote connections but you have to  configure it to do so and open the firewall. For more info see this blog post: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/28/External-Network-Access-to-Kestrel-and-IIS-Express-in-ASPNET-Core

Comment: The thing I miss the most with ASP .NET Core is **not** having to hit CTRL+F5 to run (or F5 to debug).
You just build, navigate to localhost (or whatever binding you configured) and you run your code...

Comment: You use `dotnet watch run` to do this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch. This detects changes and auto-recompiles. I think this also works when you launch IIS Express when you start in non-debug mode (ctrl-F5).

Comment: Not sure if this happens with current version, but I had issues with IIS Express, as [IApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-2.1) was behaving differently (or not calling some methods at all) in IIS Express vs. real IIS. Otherwise it seems to be [a good choice over IIS](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-iis-express).

Comment: It is not true that " there's really nothing gained by debugging through IIS"... for instance, in my case i have a self contained exe in .net 4.7.1 which uses AspNetCore 2.2, and I cannot debug startup phase inside IIS, which is different than in normal mode since application pool identity is not the same on Iis.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above suggestions, but nothing worked until I put all the missing elements together.

The essential parts of debugging in IIS are:

- Configuring IIS correctly on your dev. machine
- Installing an SSL certificate for your IIS site
- Adding Development Time IIS support from Visual Studio installer
- Installing at least .NET Core SDK 2.2
- Setting up your Launch Profile in Visual Studio to launch your browser using IIS.

.NET Core 2.2 is  needed to run your site WITHIN the IIS process.

Here's more detail:  http://intrinsicinnovation.com/Articles/2019/01/08/debugging-asp-net-core-applications-within-iis/

Comment: The link is a good one, but the answer probably needs more information from there to stand on its own. In case that link dies, similar steps are described at [MS' docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-5.0). "Development Time IIS support" is probably the key search phrase.

Comment: Really poor answer here. You need to provide more detail. This is way too general. You probably should not have provided an answer.

Comment: Craig, really poor comment here.  You probably should not have provided a useless comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through the history and stumbled upon this one.
In case anyone every comes to this question...the solution for me turned out to be quite simple.
If you're using authentication on your .net core app simply make sure it's using basic auth using HTTP(for the debug part).
Then in IIS simply use Url Rewrite to setup a reverse proxy to your http://localhost:someport .net core instance.
That's it. Problem solved.
Perhaps url rewrite will support https soon and in that case the auth basic using HTTP can be used for debugging purposes as well. Which would be great.
But so far this setup solved all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution that would allow me to debug a .NET core sub-app, while running on a website that hosts Classic ASP code.

Looooooka's reverse proxy solution worked for me, but it took some work to figure it out.

1.) Add this line to Startup.cs.

```
app.UsePathBase("/core");  // core is the name of my subdirectory
```

Make sure you put it BEFORE the line that says "app.UseStaticFiles();"

2.) Install "URL Rewrite v2" and "Application Request Routing"

3.) Add a folder to the IIS website (/core) and create a web.config file inside the folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="IISExpressReverseProxy" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:1306/core/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

4.) Open the project properties in visual studio, and go to the debug tab.  Change the "Launch browser" url to your IIS url.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API project that I wanted to run against IIS.

#### launchsettings.json

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/AspNetCore22Starter",
      "sslPort": 443
    },
```

#### IIS

Configure https binding. Also it is recommended to define a specific application pool for the web application in order to make attach process easier to find

#### Attach to process

Attach to process (Ctrl-Alt-P) + find w3wp.exe process + pick the one that has User Name = IIS APPPOOL\:

[image: Hosting process for ASP.NET Core 2.2 application]