# Cannot find dotnet.exe to debug web api (asp.net core 2.2.6)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core web api (asp.net core 2.2.6) published on a IIS local website. I have a few controllers that I'm trying to debug.

I saw on the website (docs.microsoft) that I should no longer attach the debugger to w3p.exe but to dotnet.exe instead.

The problem is that when I'm in Visual Studio (2017) I try to attach to a running process and the dotnet.exe is not visible, I cannot see it but it's correctly installed (ProgramFiles/dotnet/dotnet.exe) and I already uninstall/install .net core a few times and launch VS under admin mode but it did not work.

Does someone have an idea about this problem?

Thanks for reading,

Lio

Comment: Have you enabled the checkbox for showing processes from all users?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes :(

Comment: And do you see the w3wp.exe (matching process id) process hosting your website? What if you try attaching to w3wp process? You can find process id using IIS Worker Processes.

Comment: Ok. Any specific reason for debugging it using IIS? Cant you just use IIS Express or the application exe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296572/debugging-asp-net-core-applications-running-in-iis

Comment: Well, .NET Core is not supported in VS 2017, so that might have something to do wit it. You need VS 2019 to work with .NET Core.

Comment: Ok Mohsin, I'm such a dumbass, I should have watched more the list of process, there was 2 w3wp processes, thank you for you time, I appreciate it a lot. @ChrisPratt .Net Core works on VS2017

Comment: Only 1.1, which is EOL. 2.0+ requires VS 2019.

Comment: I work with an asp.net core 2.2.6 project on VS2017, there's no problem at all