# How to debug Blazor Webassembly on IIS with VS by attaching to Chrome?

Tags: blazor, visual-studio-debugging, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to debug a Blazor Webassembly (5.0.1) application in VS 2019 via attaching the debugger to Chrome - I can't use "direct" debugging from VS because I have a modular project structure with multiple "modules" (RCLs) placed in different VS solutions

What I tried so far:

- setting up an own IIS: [Debugging ASP.NET Core applications running in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296572/debugging-asp-net-core-applications-running-in-iis)
- starting Chrome with remote debugging port cmd: chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222

When attaching VS 2019 to Chrome, the Console.WriteLines() will show in VS output window, but no breakpoints are hit (no symbols loaded) - the "mono_wasm_runtime_ready" also shows up in the output.

When publishing, i tried with "debug" configuration, as well as "BlazorEnableCompression" set to false - nothing worked so far.

(I tried this with the default blazor-webassembly project template, also didn't work)

What am I missing? How can this be done?

Comment: check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#debug-in-the-browser). Also, please make sure that these pdb files are copied into the same folder of the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks for the link - but this only contains debugging in browser (eg Chrome) and "standard" debugging in VS - both ways aren't applicable for me - to clarify:
- I want to debug in VS via attaching a process (Chrome or w3p) to VS - and this isn't working
- I'm using a local IIS for development - so there's no issue with firewall configurations etc.. furthermore, if i set up an "IIS debug configuration" and start debugging by pressing F5, when a breakpoint is hit, VS freezes with "a debugger operation is taking a long time to complete"

Comment: One suggestion is that disable `Enable Javascript debugging for asp.net` under Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->General.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't change anything - a testproject is working fine with debugging with IIS configuration, but at a larger solution, VS freezes and I have to stop debugging - attaching chrome to VS still doesn't work (console output is shown, but no breakpoints hit) - pdb files are all copied..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this wasn't related to any of the things above - it's simply a "debugging bug":

[Unbound breakpoints when debugging in Blazor Webassembly when using certain attributes/classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65720816/unbound-breakpoints-when-debugging-in-blazor-webassembly-when-using-certain-attr/66585658#66585658)

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25380

I replaced the enums parameters in the attribues and it's working now