ASP.NET Core - deployment to IIS error: The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications
I want to publish or deploy an API using ASP.NET Core MVC. In the case of WeatherController I was able to show data but when I have used SQL data management system and retrived data from there using questions, the Controller showed me some error during the deployment in IIS. What is the solution for this error?
I have tried all the possible solutions in Goggle and StackOverflow, yet did not get any result.

Open the cmd windows, and run this command setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development".

Then you will find some errors about the db connection or something, you also could update the post later if you need further help.

I have done what u said ..yet got the same result

Ok, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452406/7687666, you can debug it , hope you can find the reason.
